# How to extend the properties in a join table generated by EF-Core-5 in a many-to-many entity relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, model-associations, ef-core-5.0

I have just created an application with ASP,Net Core 5 and EF Core 5. It requires a many-to-many relationship between two entities - Bill and User. Thus a user can have many bills and a bill can apply to many users.

```
User{
  public string Id{get; set;}
  public ICollection<Bill> Bills {get; set;}
}

Bill{
  public int Id{get; set;}
  public ICollection<User> Users {get; set;}
}
```

With EF Core 5, I learnt I should be able to ignore the join table of UserBill that contains the IDs of both Entities and a navigational properties to each of the other entities. However, I wish to make sure that no bill occurs twice for a given User.

```
UserBill{
  public string UserId{get; set;}
  public User Payer{get; set;}

  public int BillId{get; set;}
  public Bill Bill {get; set;}
}
```

So I wish to modify the join table as follows:

1. Add unique Constraint to the join table but since the join table is automatically generated by EF Core, I am looking for a way to add this unique constraint to the join table
2. Add other properties to the join table. For instance, I need to add PaymentStatus to the join table to indicate whether the bill has been paid and other properties where necessary

   ```
   UserBill{
   public int Id {get; set;}

   public string UserId{get; set;}
   public User Payer{get; set;}

   public int BillId{get; set;}
   public Bill Bill {get; set;}
   public PaymentStatus Status {get; set;}
   ```

   }

Here I now need to add unique constraint to ensure that there cannot be a multiple occurrence of

> UserId,BillId

Any assistance to get this done will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Well, if you need new properties, use a joint model. Simple as that. The convention that allows you to skip it is just to avoid having useless joint models for the default cause. Your's is not a default case, so go with it. Nothing wrong wwith that

Comment: EF creates a composite primary key on UserId and BillId in the junction table by default. As for the other properties, yes, just use an explicit junction entity.

Comment: @GertArnold, Could you please explain what you mean by "explicit junction entity"

Comment: @Tseng does it mean that EF Core will no longer create a join table by default if I create it by myself?

Comment: Yes, create it yourself. The `UserBill` you already show + the required additional properties and the composite primary key.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. I will go ahead and create the join table myself

Comment: The other question you should ask yourself, do you even need a payment status on the joint model, since a bill is paid or not. A bill can't be paid by multiple persons, since a bill is addressed to one person (natural or juristic), so only that person can pay for it

Comment: @Tseng it is actually that association of the FeeId and UserId that makes it a bill for the particular user. One fee can have multiple bills because it can belong to many users. So, I need to indicate whether that particular user has paid that particular fee. A fee like Tuition is general. It applies to many people but when it is linked with the UserId as in that join table, it becomes a bill that can be paid by only that user. That's why it is important to have payment status in that join table. Thank you for asking

Comment: Have you encountered any specific difficulty while switching to an explicitly defined join entity? If so, maybe we could answer that. Or is that you're generally unfamiliar with the process of switching to an explicitly defined join entity?

Comment: I would intuitively say that `PaymentStatus` is a property of `Bill`. Unless each `User` needs to pay seperatly for a `Bill`. But maybe a `Bill` should consist of multiple `BillParts` which each has one `User` and a `PaymentStatus`...maybe that's your `UserBill`. But I would name it differently to avoid the confusion of it being a (pure) many-to-many associative table

Comment: Well, what you write and your model is not the same. A bill is a bill, not a potion of a fee. If you have one bill linked to multiple users, that would mean multiple users get the same bill which doesn't seem right, cause it would imply that the bill is paid multiple times and I doubt thats legal anywhere. Maybe a fee should be a model of its own and have multiple invoices referenced to it and every invoice is assigned to one user. This way 1 invoice will only be issued at one user who pays it and when all bills are paid off, the fee is completely booked